# Как создать N размер массива задаваемый пользователем PASCAL

Tags: pascal

Нужно что бы пользователь мог задать N размер массива, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Укажите диалект паскаля!  В некоторых, ЕМНИП, это невозможно, а в других очень просто.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью динамических массивов. Например:

```
program p1;
var a: array of integer;
    n: integer;
begin
   readln(n); // вводим длину массива
   SetLength(a, n); // устанавливаем новую длину массива
   writeln(length(a)); // показываем длину массива
end.
```

P.S. Для написания кода использовался [PascalABC](http://pascalabc.net/ssyilki-dlya-skachivaniya)